# UNION DISTINCT with LIMITs

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain how this query gets interpreted by server?

```
(select * from mytable where <some condition> LIMIT 13)
UNION DISTINCT
(select * from mytable where <some other condition> LIMIT 103)
UNION DISTINCT
(select * from mytable where <some other condition> LIMIT 71) LIMIT 43;
```

When I tried it, it returned me 43 rows. And when I removed last `LIMIT 43` it returned me 71 rows.

So does it mean MySQL considers only last specified `LIMIT` and keeps `UNION`ing all `DISTINCT` rows from each `SELECT`s *untill* it reaches to that `LIMIT`? or how else does it work?

Answer (score 0):

p% also covers all entrys from p0% and p0% also covers all entrys from p00%. So the query doesn't really make sense to me.

I guess that p0% LIMIT 103 returns less than 71 rows therefore you get the 71 rows.

Comment: It is like: First get records starting with "p00%". Then get records starting with "p0%" (distinct, so whatever other than what starts with "p00%" within specified limit). Anyway, this question is more about usage of `UNION DISTINCT` along with `LIMIT`

Comment: But it is not intepreted like that. In your statement all the unions are equally inerpreted. You want to do something like: (select * from (select (select * from mytable where mystring like 'p%' LIMIT 71) from mytable where mystring like 'p0%' LIMIT 103) where mystring like 'p00%' LIMIT 13) which also don't make sense.

Comment: Seems you are right. But again, the question is more about how UNION DISTINCT and LIMIT works together. It was just an example query which I've changed now.